# Content sharing on Facebook after moderation

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, share

Is there a way to share website content on Facebook on form submission after an admin level moderation?
For Example: A user writes a survey on my website. At the end of the form there will be a checkbox for sharing the content on facebook. If he selects the checkbox and submits the form, the content is sent to moderation. Only when a moderator accepts the survey, it should be shared on the user's profile.

Comment: According to FB policy, only the user can post a message on his wall, not a 3rd party

Comment: You cannot force a user to post a particular text, altered by your moderator after the writing moment.